# Meaning of required operator in Lucene query syntax

Tags: lucene

I am learning about Lucene Query Syntax. I have a query that looks like this:

`black + forest`

My question is, what does this query mean? Does this say:

- Give me matches with the terms "black" and "forest" or
- Give me matches with the term "forest" that might include the term "black".

I'm trying to understand the difference between:

`+black +forest` and `black + forest` and `black +forest`

Thank you for helping me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `+black +forest` - Both black and forest are required terms.  Both must be found in any matched document.
- `black +forest` - forest is a required term, black is not.  This makes the term "black" a should clause.  The *best* matches will generally match both terms, but documents with only "forest" will also be returned, with a lower score.
- `black + forest` - The `+` here has no meaning to the query parser, it is interpreted as just another term to search for.  With `StandardAnalyzer`, this term will be eliminated, making this query effectively `black forest`.  That will return matches on both terms as the best results, and matches on either with a lower score.

  If you were using an analyzer that didn't remove punctuation (such as `KeywordAnalyzer`), your query would look like:  `defaultField:black defaultField:+ defaultField:forest`

Comment: Minor correction: the WhitespaceAnalyzer would produce such a query, the KeywordAnalyzer doesn't split at all and would produce something akin to `defaultField:(black + forest)`

Comment: @knutwalker - No, common mistake.  QueryParser syntax takes effect first, and spaces split query clauses.  That has nothing to do with the analyzer.  Clauses are analyzed after the query is parsed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, at least until 6.2 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2605?focusedCommentId=15330114&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15330114 I was under the impression that the last example somehow doesn't go through the query parser, my mistake.